# React setState of an object with count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have an array of integers from 0 to 6 as input
I need to return an object with the count of each of those numbers

```
edition = [6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2];
const [groupedEdition, setGroupedEdition] = useState([{"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0}]);
```

but I can't do the function for the set of values

```
{edition.map((prodotto) => {
    setGroupedEdition({...groupedEdition, XXXX});
})}
```

I am expecting this

```
groupedEdition = {"0": 0, "1": 2, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 1, "6": 3}
```

Can you help me?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()`

```
const edition = [6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2];
const initialValue = {"0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0};

const groupedEdition = edition.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item] += 1;
  return acc;
}, initialValue);
console.log(groupedEdition);
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but in the context of React please make sure that `intitialValue` is a copy of the `groupedEdition` (not the state object itself), so you don't mutate the React state.

Answer (score 2):

You should approach this a little different. I would do the computing separately and then assign whole result to the state. So for example do the reduce which will count the numbers and create object with number as key and count as value. Then when this is ready just assign this to the groupedPrediction.

```
const count = edition.reduce((obj, name) => {
        obj[name] = obj[name] ? ++obj[name] : 1;
        return obj;
    }, {});

setGroupedPredition(count);
```